# What would be the correct way to access these appsync graphql resources from external server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have an amplify project with a an appsync graphql api set up through amplify-cli. The project has cognito user pools integration. My goal is to have a nodeJS script on an external server perform queries on my graphql api. My question is related to correct way to set up authentication for the schema...

An excerpt of a particular model my schema I would like to access:

```
type Phase @model @auth(rules: [
{allow: private, provider: iam}
{allow: groups, groups: ["companyAdmin"], provider: userPools},
{allow: groups, groups: ["extConnection"], operations: [create, read, update], provider: userPools},
{allow: groups, groupsField: "readGroups", operations: [create, read], provider: userPools},
{allow: groups, groupsField: "editGroups", provider: userPools}]) {
    id: ID!
    description: String
    editGroups: [String]
    readGroups: [String]
}
```

My confusion stems from reading documentation on how to call the app-sync client endpoint via the nodejs @aws-sdk v3.

> Here it seems they are referring to using the connection profiles that have an iam access key id and secrey key: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html

If I create an IAM user and provide it the built in appsync access policies:

> AWSAppSyncSchemaAuthor ::: AWS managed: Provides access to create, update, and query the schema.

> AWSAppSyncPushToCloudWatchLogs ::: AWS managed: Allows AppSync to push logs to user's CloudWatch account.

and since my model has an auth rule for iam

> {allow: private, provider: iam}

I should be able to allow a particular IAM role or user to access these by adding this user to the custom-roles.json on my amplify app configuration per (since the *allow private iam* line above apparently only allows iam requests from auto generated scoped down rules): https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules/#use-iam-authorization-within-the-appsync-console ....

However, this is not ideal because I have many other models in the schema that require IAM interaction from internal lambda functions for example, but now this IAM user would have access to any model that has *allow:private provider: iam* so therefore question...

1. Can I have granular rules for the @auth directive IAM provider that limits access to a model only for a particular IAM user?

OR

2. Or should I instead use a cognito user from one of my user pools, that has the group "extConnection" which would satisfy the auth rule on this model:

> {allow: groups, groups: ["extConnection"], operations: [create, read, update], provider: userPools},

But then how would I build the the request for this via something like axios npm package to make the query? Will I need to create a REST API Gateway to handle this as a middleman between the external server and the graphql endpoint?

Comment: Hey  Michael from the Amplify devRel team, I wrote in detail how to call AppSync from a Lambda function [here](https://blog.focusotter.com/trigger-appsync-subscriptions-with-eventbridge-targets). In the post I cover permissions, as well as install node-fetch to make the call.

Comment: Hello Michael, thank you for your reply. I think you misunderstood what I was asking. I am not trying to call appsync from a lambda function. I am trying to let someone that is outside of my amplify resources/account and not using any aws services to make a graphql query against my appsync endpoint. I figured out how to do it using some  npm packages and the best way to limit access only to certain tables as per my model example above is to use cognito auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution by authenticating via cognito user pools.

1. The tables that needed to be accessed by this user, I had to limited by a user group, in this case "extConnection". So I added this group to the user account. I then used the guide written by this individual here to reach my solution: https://www.fullsapps.com/2019/02/calling-aws-appsync-or-any-graphql-api_14.html .
2. I then used the npm packages 'amazon-cognito-identity-js' and 'graphql-request' to build the cognito auth handshake headers and return the access token.
3. I used the access token to make a gql request, and that returned the needed data.

Sample code:

```
(async () => {
    /* these will need to be updated for each environment */
    const USER_NAME = 'yourusername';
    const PASS_WORD = 'yourpassword';
    const USER_POOL_ID = 'cognitopoolid';
    const CLIENT_ID = 'cognitopoolclientid';
    const ENDPOINT = 'appsyncgraphqlendpointurl';

    /* ************************************************************************ */


    function authUser() {
        // authenticates with cognito to receive the access tokens.
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const authenticationData = {
                Username: USER_NAME,
                Password: PASS_WORD
            };
            const authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
            const poolData = {
                UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID,
                ClientId: CLIENT_ID
            }
            const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
            const userData = {
                Username: authenticationData.Username,
                Pool: userPool
            }
            const cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);

            cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
                onSuccess: function (result) {
                    const idToken = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
                    const accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
                    const refreshToken = result.getRefreshToken().getToken();

                    // idToken serves our purposes for now
                    resolve(idToken);
                },
                onFailure: function (err) {
                    reject(err.message);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    async function makeQuery(gqlc) {

        const query = `mutation MyMutation {
          createPayout(input: 
            {
              status: "Pending"
            }
          ) 
          {
            id
            status
            _version
          }
        }`;
        return gqlc.request(query);
    }

    const token = await authUser();
    /* preferably cache the token somewhere and reuse in the future until it 
       expires, then re-auth */
      
    console.log(token);

    const gqlClient = new GraphQLClient(ENDPOINT, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: token
        }
    });

    
    const res = await makeQuery(gqlClient);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    }
  )();
```